# Is there a version of MySQL connector for Python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm new to Python and I just wanted to know if there is any connector for Python 3.9
I've looked at MySQL page but the last Python connector on the page (version 8.0.22) isn't compatible with the 3.9 version.

Any help? Am I not finding it or does it not exist for now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you see that the MySQL connector isn't compatible with 3.9?  Have you tried it?  How are you installing it?  `pip3 install mysql-connector-python` should work.  If it really doesn't work with 3.9, then I guess you can try the mariadb connector (`pip3 install mariadb`).

Comment: @RocketHazmat hi, I saw through MySQL Installer... The connector didn't mentioned 3.9, but I may be wrong

Comment: But thank you everyone, i've installed it from command and it worked :)

Comment: MySQL installer?  Is that a Windows thing?  I guess it's possible that MySQL didn't package the latest connector version in their installer.  Use the installer to install MySQL but not the connector.  Then use `pip` to install the connector.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, it worked as you said :) thank you!

Comment: The support for Python 3.9 will be added in the upcoming Connector/Python 8.0.24 that will be released soon. Nonetheless Connector/Python 8.0.22/23 works with Python 3.9, only the metadata in packaging doesn't comply.

Answer (score 0):

User [Nuno Mariz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7779049/nuno-mariz) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925851/mysql-connector-for-python-3-9#comment117170863_65925851)

> The support for Python 3.9 will be added in the upcoming Connector/Python 8.0.24 that will be released soon. Nonetheless Connector/Python 8.0.22/23 works with Python 3.9, only the metadata in packaging doesn't comply

So while mysql-connector-python page on pypi did not assert compatibility with Python 3.9 at the time of asking, v. 8.0.22/23 would still work if installed under Python 3.9.